# Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wordpress ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a problem that variable condition

```
Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in
```

Code:

```
<?php if( in_array( 'activar', get_field('emergente', 'options') ) ) : ?>
    ....
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any possible solution?

Comment: How about finding out what `get_field` returns exactly?

Comment: get_field returns value while u have to set that value as an array.. data type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if( is_array(get_field('emergente', 'options')) && in_array( 'activar', get_field('emergente', 'options') ) ) : ?>
    ....
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search showed that the function `get_field` does this:

> This function returns a column value.

Which I'm assuming doesn't mean array? But according to [this page](http://podsframework.org/codex/get_field) it does return an array. What I suggest is using `print_r(get_field('emergente', 'options'))` and seeing what it outputs.

You may have to do a check to see if the result `is_array` and if it's a multi dimensional array using the correct index from the returned data.